# Find previous element with jQuery - not a sibling

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, onclick

I need to attach onclick events for a number of elements. These click events need to correspond to the following element.

For example: (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vatrq17n/1/))

HTML:

```
<span class="s1">s</span>
<span class="s2">s</span>
<div class="divs"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<span class="s1">s</span>
<span class="s2">s</span>
<div class="divs"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<span class="s1">s</span>
<span class="s2">s</span>
<div class="divs"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.divs{
    background:lightblue;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
}

span{
    background:pink;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    divs = $('.divs');

    divs.each(function(){
        $this = $(this);

        s1 = $this.closest('span').find('.s1');
        s2 = $this.closest('span').find('.s2');

        s1.click(function(){
            alert('S1 click');
            $this.css('background', 'green');
        });

        s2.click(function(){
            alert('S2 click');
            $this.css('background', 'blue');
        });
    });
});
```

I want to click on any one of the span elements and perform an action on the following div.

Comment: `.next` accepts a selector as a parameter. You'd need to use `$this.next('div.divs')`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Only filtering next following elment, needs to use `.nextAll('.divs:first')`

Comment: Right on, forgot about that.

Comment: Can you demonstrate with a jsfiddle? I can't quite see how this will work, thanks :)

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/L1gof5d2/ ???

Comment: Awesome, did the trick nicely. I hadn't come across nextAll(); before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="s1">s</span>
<span class="s2">s</span>
<div class="divs"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="s1">s</span>
<span class="s2">s</span>
<div class="divs"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="s1">s</span>
<span class="s2">s</span>
<div class="divs"></div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery part:

```
$(function(){

    $('span.s1').on('click',  function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.divs').css('background', 'green');
    });

    $('span.s2').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.divs').css('background', 'blue');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to wrap your event listeners within the each function.
I'm pretty sure this will work (and reduce the amount of code):

```
$(function(){
  $('.s1').click(function() {
    alert('s1 clicked');
    // If you want to change all of the .divs
    $(this).siblings('.divs').css('background', 'green');
    // If you just want to change the first .divs
    $(this).next().next().css('background', 'green');
  });

  $('.s2').click(function() {
    alert('s2 clicked');
    // If you want to change all of the .divs
    $(this).siblings('.divs').css('background', 'blue');
    // If you just want to change the first .divs
    $(this).next().next().css('background', 'blue');
  });
});
```